# xslt split records on basis of comma

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a strange requirement where I have got couple of values inside one single element separated by comma, I have to split the records and create separate xml structure.

Below is the input:

```
<MaterialMassReplicationRequest xmlns="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global">
<MaterialMassReplicationRequest xmlns="">
    <Material>
        <SalesProcessInformation>
            <SalesOrganisationID>3520,35NZ,4200,</SalesOrganisationID>
            <SalesOrganisationIDTypeCode>917</SalesOrganisationIDTypeCode>
            <DistributionChannelCode>01</DistributionChannelCode>
            <ProductGroupCode>NORM</ProductGroupCode>
            <LifeCycleStatusCode>ACTIVE,INACTIVE,ACTIVE,</LifeCycleStatusCode>
            <SalesMeasureUnitCode>EA</SalesMeasureUnitCode>
            <MinimumOrderQuantity unitCode="EA"/>
        </SalesProcessInformation>
    </Material>
</MaterialMassReplicationRequest>
```

Expected Output:

```
<MaterialMassReplicationRequest xmlns="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global">
<MaterialMassReplicationRequest xmlns="">
    <Material>
        <SalesProcessInformation>
            <SalesOrganisationID>3520</SalesOrganisationID>
            <SalesOrganisationIDTypeCode>917</SalesOrganisationIDTypeCode>
            <DistributionChannelCode>01</DistributionChannelCode>
            <ProductGroupCode>NORM</ProductGroupCode>
            <LifeCycleStatusCode>ACTIVE</LifeCycleStatusCode>
            <SalesMeasureUnitCode>EA</SalesMeasureUnitCode>
            <MinimumOrderQuantity unitCode="EA"/>
        </SalesProcessInformation>
        <SalesProcessInformation>
            <SalesOrganisationID>35NZ</SalesOrganisationID>
            <SalesOrganisationIDTypeCode>917</SalesOrganisationIDTypeCode>
            <DistributionChannelCode>01</DistributionChannelCode>
            <ProductGroupCode>NORM</ProductGroupCode>
            <LifeCycleStatusCode>INACTIVE</LifeCycleStatusCode>
            <SalesMeasureUnitCode>EA</SalesMeasureUnitCode>
            <MinimumOrderQuantity unitCode="EA"/>
        </SalesProcessInformation>
        <SalesProcessInformation>
            <SalesOrganisationID>4200</SalesOrganisationID>
            <SalesOrganisationIDTypeCode>917</SalesOrganisationIDTypeCode>
            <DistributionChannelCode>01</DistributionChannelCode>
            <ProductGroupCode>NORM</ProductGroupCode>
            <LifeCycleStatusCode>ACTIVE</LifeCycleStatusCode>
            <SalesMeasureUnitCode>EA</SalesMeasureUnitCode>
            <MinimumOrderQuantity unitCode="EA"/>
        </SalesProcessInformation>          
    </Material>
</MaterialMassReplicationRequest>
```

honestly I am not sure how to approach this.

Thanks
Yatan

Comment: It's not a strange requirement at all - in fact, it's quite common. Do a search for *tokenize*. Note that the method depends on which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: I am using xslt 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to try and write the code for you, especially as you don't say which version of XSLT you are able to use, but I'll sketch out how I would approach this.

I would write a template for `SalesPromotionInformation` that takes a parameter with a default value of 1:

```
<xsl:template match="SalesPromotionInformation">
  <xsl:param name="occurrence" select="1"/>
  ..
```

The value of this parameter should be passed on to any child templates, either directly or using XSLT 2.0 tunnel parameters.

When processing `SalesOrganizationId` or `LifeCycleStatusCode`, use `tokenize(., ',')[$occurrence]` to extract the relevant value.

At the end of the template for `SalesPromotionInformation`, make a recursive call like this:

```
<xsl:if test="tokenize(SalesOrganisationID, ',')[$occurrence+1]">
   <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
      <xsl:with-param name="occurrence" select="$occurrence+1"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: HI Michael, I am using xslt 2.0